# How Create Nested Azure Resources using Azure SDK

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-sdk-.net, azure-batch, azure-sdk

Using ARM template, we can define a storage account under a batch account. But how we can do this using .NET SDK? Currently I can create BatchAccount and StorageAccount as separate resources, but what to do if a StorageAccount should be appeared under BatchAccount I.e. under "SETTINGS" TAB of the BatchAccount

Answer (score 0):

Below code works for me.

```
 //Getting StorageAccount to bind
var storageAccount = await storageManagementClient.StorageAccounts.GetPropertiesAsync("testresourcegroup", "teststorageaccount");

//Creating binding properties
       AutoStorageBaseProperties baseProperties = new AutoStorageBaseProperties { StorageAccountId = storageAccount.Id };

       //Creating update parametrs for Batch Account
       BatchAccountUpdateParameters updateParameters = new BatchAccountUpdateParameters { AutoStorage = baseProperties };

       //Updatting the BatchAccount to bind with chosen StorageAccount
       var response = await batchManagementClient.BatchAccount.UpdateAsync("testresourcegroup", "testbatchaccount", updateParameters);
```